# How to open file in sublime and execute with python using xargs

Tags: python, xargs, sublime-text

I'm trying to open a python script and run it at the same time using `xargs`. I've tried:

```
subl script.py | xargs python3
```

And a few other variations but none seem to work. How would you do this using `xargs`?

Comment: A pipe `|` does connect the standard output of the first command `subl script.py` to the standard input of the second command `xargs python3`. It does not pass any arguments (`script.py`) of the first command to the second command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can run first command in background and then execute second command like:

```
(subl script.py &); echo "script.py" | xargs python3
```

`(subl script.py &);` this will open the file in background and

`echo "script.py" | xargs python3` 
this will execute this script and both will be done one after another and you don't need to wait for the first command to finish.
 Second command will execute while your file will be opened in sublime.

Well above command was using `xargs` but if don't want to use `xargs` then you can also execute

```
subl script.py & python3 script.py
```

it will also do the same thing and it is short.

Comment: `subl script.py & python3 script.py` would be shorter and do the same thing.

Comment: @Kusalananda OP wants to use `xargs`

Comment: The question is whether they want to use `xargs` because they think that it would be less to type or whether they would just want to open the script in the editor and run it at the same time, as the title suggests.